# Javascript: Create array from two columns in .cvs file

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am very new at JS, here is my target & my problem:

I have a ".cvs" file, and need to select two columns, and create an Array with that two columns.

***1. CVS File:***

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7    col8    col9    col10
-1  6/10/2020   08:35:43     45.64172279    N    10.19579398    E   198.2   M   4
-1  6/10/2020   08:35:44    45.64193714 N    10.1958776 E   198.19  M   4
-1  6/10/2020   08:35:43    45.64220345 N    10.19598908    E   198.2   M   4
-1  6/10/2020   08:35:44    45.6423983  N    10.19606341    E   198.19  M   4
-1  6/10/2020   08:35:43    45.6429504  N    10.19632354    E   198.2   M   4
-1  6/10/2020   08:35:44    45.64329464 N    10.19658367    E   198.19  M   4
-1  6/10/2020   08:35:43    45.64341805 N    10.19758703    E   198.2   M   4
-1  6/10/2020   08:35:44    45.64339856 N    10.19838601    E   198.19  M   4
-1  6/10/2020   08:35:43    45.64313876 N    10.1987855 E   198.2   M   4
-1  6/10/2020   08:35:44    45.64244377 N    10.19869259    E   198.19  M   4
-1  6/10/2020   08:35:43    45.6418527  N    10.19879479    E   198.2   M   4
-1  6/10/2020   08:35:44    45.6415669  N    10.19715967    E   198.19  M   4
-1  6/10/2020   08:35:44    45.64170331 N    10.19648147    E   198.19  M   4
0   7/10/2020   09:35:44    45.64189167 N    10.19615631    E   198.19  M   4
```

***2. Read .CVS and select the columns:***

```
const response = await fetch('schio_000_orig_1.cor');
                const data = await response.text();
                // console.log(data);

                const table = data.split('\n').slice(1);
                table.forEach(row => {
                    const colums = row.split('\t');
                    const lat = colums[3];
                    const lng = colums[5];
                    console.log(lat, lng)
```

***Output by now...***

[image]

***3. Desired Output***

```
var latlng = [
                        // array
                        [ 45.64172279, 10.19579398],
                        [ 45.64193714, 10.1958776],
                        [ 45.64220345, 10.19598908],
                        [ 45.6423983, 10.19606341],
                        [ 45.6429504, 10.19632354],
                        [ 45.64329464, 10.19658367],
                        [ 45.64341805, 10.19758703],
                        [ 45.64339856, 10.19838601],
                        [ 45.64313876, 10.1987855],
                        [ 45.64244377, 10.19869259],
                        [ 45.6418527, 10.19879479],
                        [ 45.6415669, 10.19715967],
                        [ 45.64170331, 10.19648147],
                        [ 45.64189167, 10.19615631],
                    ];
```

*- Cant find the way to achieve it. I have tried push, concat, JSON.PARSE and still not getting the right array...*

Comment: `push()` should work, show your attempt to use it.

Comment: Looks like a `.tsv` file ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has the right idea, you just need to add the array to an array. Two ways of doing it would be

**Using push:**

```
const out = []
table.forEach(row => {
  const colums = row.split('\t');
  const lat = colums[3];
  const lng = colums[5];
  out.push([lat, lng]);
});
```

**Using map:**

```
const out = table.map(row => {
  const colums = row.split('\t');
  const lat = colums[3];
  const lng = colums[5];
  return [lat, lng];
});
```

Comment: You are not using map in your map example though :P

Comment: @cYrixmorten I have no idea what you are talking about... lol, bad copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a TSV file and not a CSV file (and definitely not a CVS file!). Your parsing looks like it's working, but you just want to get it from that text format to the array format. Rather than using a `forEach` you can use a `map` which produces a new array.

```
const result = table.map(row => {
  const colums = row.split('\t');
  const lat = colums[3];
  const lng = colums[5];
  return [lat, lng];
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correct, you can get the nested array result you seek by mapping over your table:

```
const response = await fetch('schio_000_orig_1.cor');
const data = await response.text();


const table = data.split('\n').slice(1);
const latlng = table.map(row => {
  const colums = row.split('\t');
  const lat = colums[3];
  const lng = colums[5];

  return [lat, lng]
});
console.log(latlng)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const response = await fetch('schio_000_orig_1.cor');
                const data = await response.text();
                const finalArray = []; // create a new array

                const table = data.split('\n').slice(1);
                table.forEach(row => {
                    const colums = row.split('\t');
                    const lat = colums[3];
                    const lng = colums[5];
                  
                  finalArray.push([lat,lng]);
                })

                console.log(finalArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nArray = [];
table.forEach(row => {
                    const colums = row.split('\t');
                    const lat = colums[3];
                    const lng = colums[5];
                    console.log(lat, lng);
// try this
nArray.push([lat, lng])
```

Comment: Please add some details/explanation when posting an answer, not just a code snippet as this is just much much less clear